# Bootstrap - Align .navbar-brand to the center but not vertically when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align my brand logo correctly for small devices, as it happens in the [official website of bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/).

For this, I am running the following:

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Company</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top pb-3">
      <div class="container-lg">
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-center" href="#">
          <img
            src="https://img.icons8.com/color/480/firebase.png"
            alt="Company"
            width="40"
            height="40"
          />
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <div class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-scroll">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But as you can see, the logo is not fixed. I mean, it moves up and down when pressing the toggler button. How can I solve it?

Also, if you notice, the height of the .navbar in small screens is different from the original one... which css rule can I apply to solve this too?

I have thought about doing:

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 60px;
}
```

but I think this is not really professional. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Removing what you have already added for.nav-brand, I believe, one of the below might work better. 

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        width: 100px;
        margin: auto !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-brand {
      margin-right: 48vw !important;
    }
}
```